# How can I use jQuery to find a particular item in the second instance of a class?

Tags: jquery

I have some markup like this.  How can I use jQuery to find and style the anchor text "Link 4"?

```
<div>
  <ul class="footer-info-list">
    <li>
      <a href="http://foo.com/link1">Link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="http://foo.com/link2">Link 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div>
  <ul class="footer-info-list">
    <li>
      <a href="http://foo.com/link3">Link 3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="http://foo.com/link4">Link 4</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Note: Please don't use the fact  that the link is the second item in the list - I need to find it using the anchor text "Link4".

Comment: Do you just want to style it?  Because that could be done with just css, no javascript.

Comment: You could use https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/

Comment: Nothing I was doing with jQuery was working.  I assumed jQuery was loaded because $ worked, but it wasn't, and that was the source of my troubles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply use `$(".footer-info-list a[href$='link4']")`

```js
$(function () {
  console.log($(".footer-info-list a[href$='link4']").text());
  $(".footer-info-list a[href$='link4']").css('color' , 'red');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul class="footer-info-list">
    <li>
      <a href="http://foo.com/link1">Link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="http://foo.com/link2">Link 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div>
  <ul class="footer-info-list">
    <li>
      <a href="http://foo.com/link3">Link 3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="http://foo.com/link4">Link 4</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

`[href$='link4']` means the element with href attribute `$` ends with `link4`

> **Note:** you can just use `$("a[href$='link4']")` if you don't have another element its `href` ends with `link4`

Comment: This finds the string perfectly - but why can I not style the result using `css()`?

Answer (score 2):

You can always use the [`.eq()`](https://api.jquery.com/eq/) to get the results you wanted. For your code:

```
$(".footer-info-list").eq(1).find("a").eq(1)
```

The above is your selector.

```js
$(function () {
  console.log($(".footer-info-list").eq(1).find("a").eq(1).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <ul class="footer-info-list">
    <li>
      <a href="http://foo.com/link1">Link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="http://foo.com/link2">Link 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div>
  <ul class="footer-info-list">
    <li>
      <a href="http://foo.com/link3">Link 3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="http://foo.com/link4">Link 4</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

> Note that `.eq()` uses zero-based index.

In case, if you are just styling, I would really recommend a CSS based approach for styling, if you ask me. This is the selector you need to use:

```
div:nth-child(2) > .footer-info-list > li:nth-child(2) > a
```

And this works in jQuery too.

```css
div:nth-child(2) > .footer-info-list > li:nth-child(2) > a {
  background: #f00;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul class="footer-info-list">
    <li>
      <a href="http://foo.com/link1">Link 1</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="http://foo.com/link2">Link 2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div>
  <ul class="footer-info-list">
    <li>
      <a href="http://foo.com/link3">Link 3</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="http://foo.com/link4">Link 4</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This is good but I was hoping to not depend on the exact position (since that could change) but rather use the anchor text.

Comment: @ScottCWilson Alright, I would have given the right solution outright, if you had mentioned that clearly. Thanks. Sure... `:)`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.eq` to get the one you want:

```js
$(function() {
    console.log($(".footer-info-list").eq(1).find("a").eq(1).css('color', 'red').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<ul class="footer-info-list">
     <li>
     <a href="http://foo.com/link1">Link 1</a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="http://foo.com/link2">Link 2</a>
     </li>
</ul>
</div>
<div>
<ul class="footer-info-list">
     <li>
     <a href="http://foo.com/link3">Link 3</a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="http://foo.com/link4">Link 4</a>
     </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You want the Nth Child selector and Sibling selectors.
The Sibling selector (+) will get you past the first div, and the nth-child() selector will get you to the second LI in the UL.
 (Docs here: https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

```js
    var child = $("div + div ul.footer-info-list li:nth-child(2)");
    child.css("background-color","red");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<ul class="footer-info-list">
     <li>
     <a href="http://foo.com/link1">Link 1</a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="http://foo.com/link2">Link 2</a>
     </li>
</ul>
</div>
<div>
<ul class="footer-info-list">
     <li>
     <a href="http://foo.com/link3">Link 3</a>
     </li>
     <li>
        <a href="http://foo.com/link4">Link 4</a>
     </li>
</ul>
</div>
```